# Auto scroll of page to specific element of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

Hi I have length jsp page and at the bottom of the page I have save button once I click the save button it will save the data to the server and once data is saved I load the same page again and I am displaying some information saying "Data is saved" at the bottom of the page.

My question is how can I load the page to show this message when page loads instead of loading page at its top.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<span> Hi </span>
.....................
.....................
.....................
.
.
.
.
.
.
//at the bottom of page
<span> Data Saved succefully</span>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I load the page I should see "Data Saved succefully" message.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply assign an id to the span and can redirect to the current page with `#your-id` attached at the end of your url.

```
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/tFcsP/show/#demo">Click to go</a>
```

Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/tFcsP/show/#demo

Comment: note that there is no need to use javascript with this solution

Answer (score 3):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/tFcsP/2/)

Try this

This will animate towards the required div or span

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    target_offset = $('#third1').offset(),
    target_top = target_offset.top;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target_top
    }, 800);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery :

```
 $(function() {       
     $(window).scrollTop($('#div_name').offset().top);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

use simple java script

```
<htm

l>
<head>
<script>
function scrollWindow()
  {
  window.scrollTo(100,500)
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="scrollWindow()" value="Scroll">
<p>SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p>SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p>SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL</p>

</body>
</html>
```

when you save the data and after say page load aur any response recieved then.

Heres w3 school link
[scroll to](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp)